# Form validation of all entries input Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't quite understand why when I go to the second entry and then to the others(input), my conditions are not taken into account. Did I make a wrong statement in terms of conditions?
In my code, I assigned rules with regex before sending it to the server. Only condition 1 works.
Thank you for your help.

```js
let inputFirstname = document.querySelector('#firstName');
let inputLastname = document.querySelector('#lastName');
let inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email');
let inputAddress = document.querySelector('#address');
let inputCity = document.querySelector('#city');



const regexName = /^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$/;
const regexMail = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,10}$');
const regexNumber = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
const regexAdress = /^(([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+[\s\-]{1}[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+)){1,20}$/;



document.querySelector('#formContact').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Test FIRSTNAME // 

    if (regexName.test(inputFirstname.value)){
        inputFirstname.style.border = " #7EEA5E solid 2px";
        return true;
    }

    //Test LASTNAME // 
    if (regexName.test(inputLastname.value)) {
        inputLastname.style.border = " #7EEA5E solid 2px";
        return true;
    }

    //Test EMAIL // 
    if (regexMail.test(inputEmail.value)) {
        inputEmail.style.border = " #7EEA5E solid 2px";
        return true;
    }

    // Test ADRESS //
    if (regexAdress.test(inputAddress.value)) {
        inputAddress.style.border = " #7EEA5E solid 2px";
        return true;
    }

    // Test CITY //
    if (regexName.test(inputCity.value)) {
        inputCity.style.border = " #EA6B5E solid 2px";
        return true;
    }


    else {
        alert('Good !');
    }

});
```

```html
 <form action="/" method="post" class="row gy-4" id="formContact">
                      

                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label for="firstName">Firstname *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                                value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>


                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Lastname *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder=""
                                value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email *</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                                placeholder="mail@example.com" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="address" class="form-label">Adress *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address"
                                placeholder="Rue, avenue" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city" class="form-label">City *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>



                        <div class=" form-group my-4 text-center ">
                            <button class="btn  btnSubmit fw-bold btn-secondary" type="submit"
                                value="">Order</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: your alert triggers every time one of your conditions is not met. they way I would approach this is to run the validation on `Order` click, and not on every change of the form

Comment: It's because you return true within each check. As soon as the first return is met, the code will exit the function. 
Remove the returns from the check and you should be good to go

Comment: @NikosGkogkopoulos ok thank you, I will put click and I will check if it's okay.

Comment: @D.Schaller I must then also remove my return property for all input?

Comment: @D.Schaller It works because of you. I have a small last question I can add a condition, in particular a message to warn the user that the form is correct? I have a problem I want to transform my form into a contact object, can I create a variable inside?

Comment: @ninstudic Check my answer, I reworked your code as an example of how you would approach this, with some explanations

Comment: @D.Schaller Thank your very much

Comment: @D.Schaller It's much clearer to me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` calls in your checks exit the whole function on first met condition.

I played a bit around and reworked your code.

Your initial problem was, that you had one function, testing everything even if only one thing changed. On top of that, you wanted to return within each check. The [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) will exit the function entirely when called. Therefore nothing but your first check came through.

You could avoid this by using a switch case and checking depending on your event.target.id which check you want to run.

I introduced a "global" error variable which defaults to true.
After each check this variable is being updated accordingly.

I added a eventListener with Click on your Order Button, which will only send if `error = false`, otherwise show an alert. Even though I wouldn't use an altert in production code, since it will HALT your entire code, which might cause problems if you're about to work with async calls.

A message for the user to inform him that everything is ready to be sent seems a bit over the top, since you want to color every field as its updated.

```js
let error = true;

const regexName = /^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$/;
const regexMail = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,10}$');
const regexNumber = /^[0-9]{5}$/;
const regexAdress = /^(([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+[\s\-]{1}[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]+)){1,20}$/;



document.querySelector('#formContact').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const borderCode = " #7EEA5E solid 2px";
    
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'firstName':
        if(regexName.test(e.target.value)) {
        error = false;
        } else {
        error = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'lastName':
        if(regexName.test(e.target.value)) {
        error = false;
        } else {
        error = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'email':
        if(regexMail.test(e.target.value)) {
        error = false;
        } else {
        error = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'address':
        if(regexMail.test(e.target.value)) {
        error = false;
        } else {
        error = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'city':
        if(regexName.test(e.target.value)) {
        error = false;
        } else {
        error = true;
        }
        break;  
    }
    
    if (!error) {
      e.target.style.border = borderCode;
    }
});

document.querySelector('#submitButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if(error) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Some Inputs are not valid.');
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="/" method="post" class="row gy-4" id="formContact">
                      

                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label for="firstName">Firstname *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                                value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>


                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Lastname *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder=""
                                value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email *</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                                placeholder="mail@example.com" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="address" class="form-label">Adress *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address"
                                placeholder="Rue, avenue" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>

                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city" class="form-label">City *</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" value="">
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>



                        <div class=" form-group my-4 text-center ">
                            <button class="btn  btnSubmit fw-bold btn-secondary" type="submit"
                            id="submitButton"    value="">Order</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```